# How to change image of a button on hover

Tags: css, button

I want to be able to when the user hovers over the button the button image changes. Thanks

```
<input type="image" src="qmb.png" name="saveForm" class="btTxt submit" id="button" height="49.5px" padding = "0px"/>


 #button {
    text-align:center;
    float:left;

    }

    #button:hover {
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    background-image: url('qmb2.png')

    }
```

Comment: `background-image: url('qmb2')` what is `qmb2` is it jpg or png or what?

Comment: png and is still does not work

Answer (score 2):

This should resolve the problem, remove the image from HTML input

```
<input type="image" name="saveForm" class="btTxt submit" id="button" height="49.5px" padding = "0px"/>
```

and put it here in CSS

```
#button {
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    background-image: url('qmb.png')
}

#button:hover {
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    background-image: url('qmb2.png')
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3rj34vjc/)

Comment: That caused both images to disappear.  If the png is from my computer and not the internet would I still use url and not src?

Comment: should use the correct path here `background-image: url('qmb.png')` and `background-image: url('qmb2.png')`  currently it is looking for images in root if you have images in folder then change it like `background-image: url('folder/qmb.png')`

Comment: quick questions quick answer, where is your css located, root or inside folder and whats the folder name, where are images located, in root or inside folder and whats the folder name?

Comment: Css is above the body, inside the folder name Max Got Bored.

Comment: if  `Max Got Bored` then add in css like this `Max%20Got%20Bored/qmb.png` by the way spacing in folder name not good approach, either use `-` or `_` like `Max-Got-Bored` or `Max_Got_Bored`

Answer (score 1):

```
#button:hover {
background-image: url('qmb2.png')
}
```

also, on hover you don't need to repeat again all the properties